# Selected Images Not Displaying In Order

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I am building a Vote/Instagram-type app, where a user selects a non-user-made photo  which is pushed into a Timeline.

I have built out the selection screen and button, and the Timeline. For some reason, I can only guess that it has something to do with the chronology of saving the PFObject (the chose photo), the Timeline is displaying the photo chosen BEFORE the currently chosen photo.

The following block is the 'Select' button on the 'SelectScreenVC':

```
@IBAction func selectNext(sender: UIButton) {
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(lgImgURL.image)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "\(cName.text!)", data: imageData)

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user["nextChosen"] = "\(cName.text!)"
    user["imageFile"] = imageFile

    var userNextPhoto = PFObject(className: "UserNextPhoto")

    userNextPhoto["username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username
    userNextPhoto["cName"] = "\(cName.text!)" as String
    userNextPhoto["imageFile"] = imageFile

    userNextPhoto.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("User \(PFUser.currentUser().username) chose: \(self.cName.text!)")
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(timeLineVC, animated: true)
}
```

---

This the TimeLineVC. I have the function which creates the timeline array and I skipped some of the TableView methods, except for the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
class TimeLineViewController: UITableViewController {

var timelineData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData()
}

func loadData() {
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "UserNextPhoto")


    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {
                self.timelineData.addObject(object)
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }

        let array: NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
        self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("timelineCell", forIndexPath:    indexPath) as TimelineTableViewCell
    let userNextPhoto:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

    let nextPhoto:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
    cell.usernameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser().username
    cell.cName.text = (userNextPhoto["cName"] as String)
    return cell
}
```

I appreciate any help or insight!

Comment: Did you try adding `[findTimelineData orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];` just before firing your Parse query (the `findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` line)?

Comment: Yes I tried this however I get the same result. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 2):

That is what is going on: the new photo has not finished uploading when you pop the view controller. You can either wait for the photo to finish uploading (which is not a great UX), or you can pass back a reference to the newly-saved object back up to the popped view controller which can then display the new photo right away without waiting for the upload to finish.

Comment: Hi Hector thanks for the insight. So out of curiousity, because the photo hasn't loaded the function automatically loads the next item in the array? I ask because at this point I was just testing the username, timestamp and name of the photo, without even trying to display the photo yet. Also, how would I pass the reference back before the ViewController is popped? Thanks again for your help.